# Python Pandas: concatenating multiple row values for each index value

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

For this given sample data frame
[Starting data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbAqG.png)
I would like to concatenate the values for "Level 1" and "Level 2" for each unique project, returning

[Required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RDgo.png)
The result should contain only a single row for every project, with each of the related values in "Level 1" and "Level 2" concatenated and separated with a bar symbol.

I am currently using a rather slow solution involving populating a dictionary while looping over the data frame, but was wondering if a faster execution could be achieved by using methods that use the full power of pandas.

Comment: Please don't use images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

I will add the DF code to make things easier for others as well.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'project': [1,1,1,1,1,2,3], 'Level 1' : ['Fruit', 'Fruit', 
'Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Vegetable', 'Fruit', 'Vegetable'], 'Level 2' : ['Apple', 
'Banana', 'Lemon', 'Carrot', 'Tomato', 'Banana', 'Cucumber']})
df.set_index('project', inplace = True)

grouped = df.groupby(df.index).agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x.unique()))
```

Comment: This is very close already to the required result.
For project 1, the concatenated result for Level 1 returns "Fruit|Fruit|Fruit|Vegetable|Vegetable", where it should be "Fruit|Vegetable".  There is no need for duplicates, if these could be removed and result in "Fruit|Vegetable", then that would be perfect.

Comment: Just change `x` in the `lambda` function to `x.unique()` as the other user has shown. I will go ahead and edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it gives me an entry point for further learning the secret powers of pandas.
Very much appreciated, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

You can perform `groupby` w.r.t the index axis. Aggregate all the columns by joining them with `sep="|"` after selecting all unique elements corresponding to each group.

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda grp: '|'.join(grp.unique()))
```

[image]

***Data:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'project': [1,1,1,1,1,2,3],
                   'Level 1': ['Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Vegetable', 'Fruit', 'Vegetable'],
                   'Level 2': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon', 'Carrot', 'Tomato', 'Banana', 'Cucumber']})
df.set_index('project', inplace=True)
```